# Using chained methods with Graphics2D

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, graphics2d

```
public class FaceComponent extends JComponent
{  
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
   {  
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
      Ellipse2D.Double head = new Ellipse2D.Double(5, 10, 100, 150);
      Rectangle eye = new Rectangle(25, 70, 15, 15);
      Line2D.Double mouth = new Line2D.Double(30, 110, 80, 110);
      g2.setColor(Color.GREEN)
        .fill(eye)
        .eye.translate(50, 0);
        .fill(eye)
        .setColor(Color.RED)
        .draw(mouth)
        .setColor(Color.BLUE)
        .drawString("Hello, World!", 5, 175);
   }
}
```

Is there a reason chaining the methods on object g2 causes error "cannot invoke (method) on primitive type void, which I may be overlooking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The methods [`setColor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#setColor-java.awt.Color-), `fill`, etc. have void return types so can't be chained like this, rather they need to be invoked separately

```
g2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
g2.fill(eye);
...
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't chain method calls like that on your Graphics object since its method calls do not return a Graphics object but rather return void.

change

```
  g2.setColor(Color.GREEN)
    .fill(eye)
    .eye.translate(50, 0);
    .fill(eye)
    .setColor(Color.RED)
    .draw(mouth)
    .setColor(Color.BLUE)
    .drawString("Hello, World!", 5, 175);
```

to

```
  g2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
  g2.fill(eye);
  g2.eye.translate(50, 0);
  g2.fill(eye);
  g2.setColor(Color.RED);
  g2.draw(mouth);
  g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
  g2.drawString("Hello, World!", 5, 175);
```

In fact, none of Graphics or Graphics2D methods returns an instance of itself. The `create()` method does return a Graphics object but not the same one. A quick look at the API would show you this, and in the future, this is what I recommend that you do for similar questions.